# How to use RCTConvert in react

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, native-module, bridging

I am new to react and working on react bridging modules. I just want to know that how the RCTConvert is useful and how can use that. I am following this site
[link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html)

Please, anyone helps me to know about this stuff.

Comment: It looks like that class is to help pass various data types from the native side of the code into a JSON data type that can be handle by the javascript on the react-native side. Do you have a specific question about it?

Comment: I just want to know the difference between

    NSString *location = details[@"location"];
 NSLog(@"location ==========>>%@",location);
 NSString *location1 = [RCTConvert NSString:details[@"location"]];  NSLog(@"location1 is ==========>>%@",location1);

In both cases I'm getting the same output.

Comment: Sorrry I don't know much about the difference. If you're getting the same output does that affect you?

Comment: No. I just want to know the difference.

Comment: After searching google, I found that it is used to convert JSON Objects into native types. Here the link http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/React/0.2.0/Classes/RCTConvert.html

Answer (score 5):

The `RCTConvert` helper functions all accept a JSON value as input and map it to a native Objective-C type or class. It's useful to convert basic supported input parameter types such as `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary` to other ones: `NSURL`, `UIColor`, `CGRect` etc. which are not supported by the React bridge. For instance:

Java Script:

```js
Module.setPosition({x : 10, y: 20});
```

ObjC:

```objectivec
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(setPosition:(id)position) {
    CGPoint point = [RCTConvert CGPoint:position];
    NSLog(@"x: %f, y: %f", point.x, point.y);
}

// Prints: x: 10.000000, y: 20.000000
```

Also it's possible to extend `RCTConvert` with `RCT_CUSTOM_CONVERTER` macro for your custom types:

Java Script:

```js
Module.addUser({name : 'John', email: 'joghn@domain.com'});
```

ObjC:

```objectivec
typedef struct {
    NSString* name;
    NSString* email;
} User;

User createUser(NSString* name, NSString* email) {
    User user;
    user.name = name;
    user.email = email;
    return user;
};

@implementation RCTConvert (User)

RCT_CUSTOM_CONVERTER(User, User, createUser(json[@"name"], json[@"email"]) )

@end

...

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(addUser:(id)user) {
    User new_user = [RCTConvert User:user];
    NSLog(@"name: %@, email: %@", new_user.name, new_user.email);
}

// Prints: name: John, email: joghn@domain.com
```

For simple types such as `NSString` it does type checking and rices the conversion error if you try to cast to the other type so that is very important in debugging. This is code for that from the sources:

RCTConvert.h

```objectivec
+ (NSString *)NSString:(id)json;
```

RCTConvert.m

```objectivec
/**
 * This macro is used for creating converter functions for directly
 * representable json values that require no conversion.
 */
#if RCT_DEBUG
#define RCT_JSON_CONVERTER(type)             \
  +(type *)type : (id)json                   \
  {                                          \
    if ([json isKindOfClass:[type class]]) { \
      return json;                           \
    } else if (json) {                       \
      RCTLogConvertError(json, @ #type);     \
    }                                        \
    return nil;                              \
  }
#else
#define RCT_JSON_CONVERTER(type) \
  +(type *)type : (id)json       \
  {                              \
    return json;                 \
  }
#endif

RCT_JSON_CONVERTER(NSArray)
RCT_JSON_CONVERTER(NSDictionary)
RCT_JSON_CONVERTER(NSString)
RCT_JSON_CONVERTER(NSNumber)
```

For more samples how to use `RCTConvert` you can look at the sources: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Base/RCTConvert.m